# How to use an API based on the OAuth2.0 protocol

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, fetch-api

I'm new to API requests and JavaScript.

I try to use an API based on the OAuth2.0 protocol (Authorisation Code Grant).

I don't understand how I can pass the first step:

- why my request don't generate the redirection to the `redirect_uri`?
- after, how to catch the URL params contain in this redirection URL ?

Here, my actual code :

```js
const link = 'https://gw.hml.api.fr/group/espace-particuliers/consentement/oauth2/authorize?client_id=MY_API_CLIENT_ID&state=fz80ac780&duration=P6M&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://gw.hml.api.fr/redirect';
  
const connect = document.getElementById('connect-btn')
if (connect) {
  connect.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(link)
        .then(response => response.text())
          console.log(response);
        // HOW TO CATCH THE REDIRECTION_URI PARAMS ?

  });
};
```

Exemple of response :

```html
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Veuillez patienter...</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * Delete cookies (iPlanetDirectoryPro, amlbcookie)
         */
        function removeCookie(cookieName) {
            cookieValue = "";
            cookieLifetime = -1;
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (cookieLifetime*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie = cookieName+"=" + JSON.stringify(cookieValue) + expires+"; path=/; domain=.ene.fr";
        }
        removeCookie("iPlanetDirectoryPro");
        removeCookie("amlbcookie");

        /**
         * Parse url query
         */
        var parseQueryString = function( queryString ) {
            var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
            // Split into key/value pairs
            queries = queryString.split("&");
            // Convert the array of strings into an object
            for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
                temp = queries[i].split('=');
                params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
            }
            return params;
        };
        var url = "https://gw.hml.api.fr/redirect?code=sD4F5RT3qPPJ15qFhrGu32YiumzN5D&state=fz80ac780&usage_point_id=225158214714453";

        // Get redirect_uri params
        var queryString            = url.substring( url.indexOf('?') + 1 );
        var params                 = parseQueryString(queryString);
        var forceNonAutomaticClose = params.close !== undefined && params.close == 'false';

        // Avoid closing popup
        if (forceNonAutomaticClose || !this.window.opener || this.window.opener.closed) {
            this.window.location.href = url;
        } else if (this.window.opener && !this.window.opener.closed) {
            // Close popup
            this.window.opener.location.href = url;
            this.window.close();
        }
    
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I complete my code?

Comment: Do you have a web server? The redirect_uri is a page on your web server that processes the OAuth 2.0 response (e.g. you write the code for that web page). Based on your `link` at the top of your code, you are using `implicit` which means you should use `reponse_type=token` and not `response_type=code`. Implicit does not use Client Secret.

Comment: Another item. If you want to use Authorization Code Grant, your code runs on a web server and not in your browser and requires the Client ID and Client Secret.

Comment: Yes, in my real code, i have set the `client_id` and `client_secret` with the good values... and the doc of the API tel me to use `response_type=code`...

Comment: Where in your docs does it tell you to put the Client Secret in your browser? This is huge security hole. Code that handles OAuth Client Secret runs at the server.

Comment: Yes, for this first request, i have only the `client_id' in my `link'. The `client_secret`is for POST requests and runs at the server.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question and show your server code and ask how to handle all of this at the server. The browser follows redirects that your server and OAuth generate. Your server receives the tokens, not your browser.